# Custom form in WaveMaker

Tags: wavemaker

We user Wavemaker to develop our app.

In our app, we have a form which has to be dynamic, based on a JSON.

To detail, we have multiple form templates stored as JSON. And that JSON will say everything about the form.

I am new to Wavemaker and didn't get much from documentation. What is the right way to create a dynamic form from that JSON?

Comment: Where is the JSON for the forms stored?? Does it need to be retrieved? You can place a blank form on your canvas and create widgets using javascript..

Comment: They are stored in Wavemaker DB. Thanks for the suggestion. At last done with Javascript.

Comment: This will probably help you creating widgets at runtime:  http://dev.wavemaker.com/wiki/bin/Dev/Custom+Code#HCreatingWidgetsatRuntime